# React render array of objects in cells of Bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, render, jsx

I have an array of components and I want to render each element in a different cell. The length of the array can be always different and can be more then 12 elements that are the limit of the cells in the Bootstrap grid system. So if the elements are more then 12 I need to create a new rows.

In my RENDER method I have this:

```
let components = this.state.elements.map(
  (currElement, index) => this.renderElement(currElement, index)
);
return (
  <div className="wrap-content container-fluid">
      <section id="box-main" className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row flex-items-xs-center">
            <div className="col-xs">
                <header>
                  <h4>{this._title}</h4>
                </header>
            </div>
          </div>   
            {components}  
      </section>
  </div>);
```

The method renderElement now render each element in a row, but I want to render in a cell but I don't know how to do. The **ElementItem** is a component that render the single element.

```
renderElement(element, index)
{
  return(
    <div key={index} className="row flex-items-xs-center">
        <div  className="col-xs">
          <ElementItem element={element} propA={element.propA} template={2} />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an online demo sample? I created a [CodePen Template](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/gjyBqB) if you want you can update it to you example.

Comment: Thank you Cristian, I have red to late this comment. I solved with solution of Dupocas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian, I'm not sure if I understood your question. But if you want each element rendered in a column(cell) you must declare your components inside `row` and then specify the breakpoints. Something like this:

```
const MainComponent = props =>{
    const elements = elements.map(element =>{
        return(<div className="col md-4"> {element} </div>);
    })
    return(
        <div className="row">
           {elements}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was in confusion and I didn't think about this solution.

Comment: Yeah...but what about if elements contains more than 3 values? Like if it had say, 5 components in it, you'd have to create a new row to hold the next 2 children isn't it? So how do you go about that?